# Connect "monitor-less" computer to a laptop with a cable

Tags: windows, networking, laptop, connection, desktop-computer

The idea is to connect both computers using a VGA cable and make my laptop's VGA port receive the image from my desktop computer. Is there a way to do it?

Specs:

- OS: Windows 7 (desktop) / 8 (laptop)
- Graphic cards: NVidia GeForce

Please tell me if I need to mention more details or explain further.

Thank you.

EDIT: I can use my desktop computer by borrowing a monitor but I don't have a permanent one for it
EDIT 2: In the end, I want to open my desktop computer without needing a monitor (since I don't want to buy a new one because it takes money and space...). I alse have RG-45 cable so a network solution is welcome too.

Comment: Video cards are output only, so either you will need to tell us what VGA capture card you are using or go out and buy one (Shopping recommendations are off topic)

Comment: @DragonLord I looked into MaxVista but in the manual I found "Each PC must have its own monitor" -> not gonna help.

Comment: @DragonLord
As for Synergy, it seems like a good idea to try but I don't know if it also needs a permanent monitor.

Comment: In a word, NO.  (But more words are required to get past the character limit.)  You can, of course, use some sort of remote desktop connection.

Answer (score 5):

Your laptop VGA is a one way street out. That being said, as ernie suggested try remote desktop solution. Depending on what your needs are you can try Windows Remote Desktop Connection or possibly Google Remote Desktop(extension and client for Chrome Browser)

Answer (score 3):

Laptop monitors generally use an LVDS connection, not a standard VGA input, so there's no easy way to do this.

If your laptop is working, you could use a remote desktop type solution to see the image.

Alternatively, if you just want to salvage the laptop display to use with a computer, you may be able to use an [LVDS to VGA convertor board](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Convert-a-Laptop-LCD-into-an-External-Monit/#intro), but it's probably more cost (time and dollars) efficient to buy a real display.